# Datatables and ajax data formatting?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, datatables

I am using Datatables and I want to be able to send an AJAX request to get my data.

**My jQuery -**

```
$('.valid-tags').DataTable( {
    "ajax": {
        "url": "/ajax/getValidTags.php",
        "type": "POST",
        "data": {
            ruleID: ruleID
        }
    }
} );
```

**This is the data returned from the ajax request -**

```
{"data":["K":2,"B":1,"C":2]}
```

Im expecting to see 'K', 'B', 'C' under tag name in their own rows.

[image]

My Datatables doesn't load any data though?

I need to be able to wrap each key value pair in its own array so this -

```
{"data":["K":2,"B":1,"C":2]}
```

Would be -

```
{"data":[["K":2],["B":1],["C":2]]}
```

This is the PHP that builds it (where do i wrap the key values in an object so it like the above)?-

```
$validTagsArray = array();
$validArray = array();

foreach ($cursor as $key => $value) {
  foreach ($value['AutoFix'] as $k => $v) {
    $x = 0;
    foreach ($v as $key => $value) {
      $x++;
      $validValueCount = $validTagsArray[$k] = $x;
    }
  }
}

$validArray['data'] = array($validTagsArray);


echo json_encode($validArray);
```

Comment: Initialize the datatable after getting your ajax function. `.success function(){$('.valid-tags').DataTable()}`. Also make sure you have the same number of columns in the table ;)

Comment: @Bruno this didn't work but thanks.

Comment: are you using `columns.data` ?(https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/objects.html) ?

Comment: @Bruno what does 'data' and 'date' relate to?

Comment: @Bruno this is the data I'm using, I need each of these `{"K":2,"B":1,"C":2}` to be in the Tag Name column

Comment: Oh I see. Let me try make a fiddle for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the format of the JSON that you're returning as shown below. See [Data source types](http://datatables.net/manual/data/#Data-source-types) for more information.

```
{
    "data": [
        [ "K", 2 ],
        [ "B", 1 ],
        [ "C", 2 ]
    ]
}
```

Change your initialization options as shown below.

```
$('.valid-tags').DataTable( {
    "ajax": {
        "url": "/ajax/getValidTags.php",
        "type": "POST",
        "data": {
            ruleID: ruleID
        }
    },
    "columnDefs": [{
       "targets": 2,
       "render": function(data, type, full, meta){
          return '<button type="button">Manage</button>';
       }
    }]
} );
```

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k867LLyt/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: The problem is, I need K, B, C under tag name in separate rows. And the values under Autofixes.

Comment: not sure whats different but I get No data available in table

Comment: @Kieron606, check whether output matches what is shown in my answer. Also check for console errors.

Comment: I have edited  my post and I am getting a different output see above

Comment: @Kieron606, You're not producing the output correctly. Change your PHP to ` $validArray['data'][] = array($k, $v);` in the `foreach` loop and remove `$validArray['data'] = array($validTagsArray)` line.