# Invalid JSON Response from datatable server side

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, datatables

I'm using the jQuery Datatable plugin and started doing a server-side activation due to the large volume of data being registered.

I did everything with the same basics, just as it is in the documentation, but when loading it it informs an alert:

> Warning DataTables: table id = example - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, see http://datatables.net/tn/1.

Following as instructions, I debugged, and in the last step, where it is to show the JSON with the data, it appears: *This request has no response data available.*

Why is this error still happening? **Detail:** If I change JUST the fields, on the server_processing.php page in the default it works perfectly, is the database?

The page with the **simple.html** table:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" class="init">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "scripts/server_processing.php"
    } );
    (function() {
    var url = '//debug.datatables.net/bookmarklet/DT_Debug.js';
    if (typeof DT_Debug != 'undefined') {
        if (DT_Debug.instance !== null) {
            DT_Debug.close();
        } else {
            new DT_Debug();
        }
    } else {
        var n = document.createElement('script');
        n.setAttribute('language', 'JavaScript');
        n.setAttribute('src', url + '?rand=' + new Date().getTime());
        document.body.appendChild(n);
    }
})();
} );

    </script>
</head>
<body class="dt-example">
    <div class="container">
        <section>
            <div class="demo-html"></div>
            <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Razão Social</th>
                        <th>CNPJ</th>
                        <th>CEP</th>
                        <th>Rua</th>
                        <th>Cidade</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
        </section>
    </div>
    <br>
</body>
```

And **server_processing.php**:

```
<?php
$table = 'tbl_company';
$primaryKey = 'id_Company';

$columns = array(
    array( 'db' => 'id_Company', 'dt' => 0 ),
    array( 'db' => 'razaoSocial',  'dt' => 1 ),
    array( 'db' => 'cnpj',   'dt' => 2 ),
    array( 'db' => 'cep',     'dt' => 3 ),
    array( 'db' => 'rua',   'dt' => 4 ),
    array( 'db' => 'cidade',     'dt' => 5 )
);


$sql_details = array(
    'user' => '***', //User
    'pass' => '***', //Pass
    'db'   => '***', //DB
    'host' => 'localhost'
);

require_once( 'ssp.class.php' );
echo json_encode(
    SSP::simple( $_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns )
);
```

I even did another debug, the datatable debugger, [here is the response](http://debug.datatables.net/ujutog). Nothing.

Comment: The error says it all. You are sending an unrecognized Json. The PHP code it's wrong.

Comment: What kind of database are you using?

Comment: Mysql @JoseMarques

Comment: Where is wrong?

Comment: when you code your JSON.

Comment: I have no time for correcting your code now so give a look at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36498951/datatables-and-ajax-data-formatting Another thing you should consider the injection into the database, always use prepared statement. If you are not able to correct the code I will try to correct for you later.

Comment: Still didn't understand, Can't see why my JSON response it's wrong @JoseMarques

Comment: What is your SSP::simple() call returning?

Comment: Nothing *This request has no response data available* @Rob

Comment: JohnDoe404 - that may be what your browser is telling you, but that's not necessarily what that function call is returning.  You need to find that out.  It's possible it's just returning null or false.

Comment: And how to find out @Rob?